# Stripe server webhooks en angular

Tags: nodejs, server, stripe, webhook

Estoy integrando un servidor stripe. Estoy usando los webhooks de stripe, el webhook funciona y recibo la los eventos bien en mi servidor. El tema es que por ejempo aunque recibo un cualquier_evento.succes , en la consola de stripe cli recimo una respuesta positiva pero con codigo 400 como si fuera un error. Pero tanto en stripe como en mi aplicacion recibo el evento correctamente.

Lo curioso es que si elimino la parte del try catch , en stripe cli recibo un codigo 200. Entonces no se si puedo o debo quitar esa parte del codigo.

Este en mi codigo del servidor:

```
app.post('/webhook', express.raw({ type: 'application/json' }), 
   async (req, res) => { 
  
     console.log(req.body); 
  
     const sig = req.headers['stripe-signature']; 
     const event = req.body; 
     console.log(event.data.object); 
  
     let subscriptionSchedule; 
  
      
     try { 
       event = stripe.webhooks.constructEvent(req.body, sig, endpointSecret); 
  
     } catch (err) { 
       res.status(400).send(`Webhook Error: ${err.message}`); 
       return; 
     } 
     
     // Handle the event 
      
     switch (event.type) { 
       case 'subscription_schedule.aborted': 
         subscriptionSchedule = event.data.object; 
         // Then define and call a function to handle the event subscription_schedule.aborted 
         break; 
       case 'subscription_schedule.canceled': 
         subscriptionSchedule = event.data.object; 
         // Then define and call a function to handle the event subscription_schedule.canceled 
         break; 
       case 'subscription_schedule.completed': 
         subscriptionSchedule = event.data.object; 
         console.log(`subscriptiont was successful for ${subscriptionSchedule}`); 
         // Then define and call a function to handle the event subscription_schedule.completed 
         break; 
       case 'subscription_schedule.created': 
         subscriptionSchedule = event.data.object; 
         console.log(`PaymentIntent was successful for ${subscriptionSchedule}!`) 
         // Then define and call a function to handle the event subscription_schedule.created 
         break; 
       case 'subscription_schedule.expiring': 
         subscriptionSchedule = event.data.object; 
         // Then define and call a function to handle the event subscription_schedule.expiring 
         break; 
       case 'subscription_schedule.released': 
         const subscriptionSchedule = event.data.object; 
         // Then define and call a function to handle the event subscription_schedule.released 
         break; 
       case 'subscription_schedule.updated': 
         subscriptionSchedule = event.data.object; 
         // Then define and call a function to handle the event subscription_schedule.updated 
         break; 
       default: 
         console.log(`Unhandled event type ${event.type}`); 
     } 
     
  
  
     // Return a 200 response to acknowledge receipt of the event 
     //response.send(); 
     res.json({ received: true }); 
   });
```

He usado la documentación de stripe.